# How do I get my value to print every time the loop increments in Java (For Loop)

Tags: java

I need to create a code that prints a pyramid like structure, given the user integer input which will be printed last. (I have attached an image of a final product below). I am new to programming, have been enjoying it, but am stuck in this problem.

My code can currently produce the user input 4 times. So I feel like I am close, just a little bit of tweaking will get the job done

I need my code to print out every single time that the loop increments instead of just displaying the user input a certain amount of times. I converted the integer to a string so that I can show the value x amount of times, but I feel that this is what is throwing me off. If I can somehow get the string to display the values at every incrementation then I will be golden. PLEASE HELP! Below is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner; //import scanner

public class NumberStack { // class

static Scanner myScanner; //declare scanner

public static void main(String[] args){ //add main method
    myScanner= new Scanner (System.in); //scanner input declaration
    int input= 0;

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter an integer between 0 and 9 inclusive: ");
        if (!myScanner.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("You have not entered an integer");
        }
        input= myScanner.nextInt();
        if ( (input>=0) && (input<=9) ) {

            String smln= Integer.toString(input);
            String out="";

                for (int p=0; p<input; p++) {    
                    for (int j=0; j<input; j++) {    
                        for (int i=0; i<((input*2)-1);i++) {

                            out += smln;

                        }
                        System.out.println(""+out); 
                        out="";
                        smln= Integer.toString(input);
                    }
                }


        } //end of if statement
        else {
            System.out.println("You have not entered an integer within range");
        }

    } //end of while loop


} //end of main method
} //end of class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are facing problems like this one, you should try to look for a pattern...check this out

```
        int input = 4;

        for(int i = 1; i <= input; i++)
        {
            int times = i;
            int length = 2 * i - 1;
            String str = "";
            for(int j = 0; j < length; j++)
            {
                str += i;
            }
            for(int k = 0; k < times; k++)
            {
                System.out.println(str);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Big help; finding a pattern was my first approach but I couldn't expand on it. I think I was so used to just nesting for loops within each other but didn't realize that nesting two separate ones into one will do the trick. Thanks for the big help!

Comment: i know, it happened to me a lot of times...well, always remember: Solve the problem before programming it.

Answer (score 0):

Since your method is currently printing the data fro a particular number properly eg for input 4  it is printing

```
4444
4444
4444
4444
```

I would suggest that extract ur code for display into a separate function. And call that function using the number from a loop.

```
for(int i=1; i<=num;i++)
  function_f1(i);
```

This should do the trick for you and since you are starting off with coding , it will also give you ideas on using methods.

Comment: This worked like a charm, I will definitely expand my code in this way for future problems. Great way to expand a concept.

Comment: Good that I could help you out with. If possible kindly vote up and mark my answer. Thanks.